# How to tell if -nw (no window) is in args?

Tags: init-file

I want a single .emacs but one that branches depending on whether `-nw` was in the argument list. (open in terminal [no window mode])

I.e, in gui mode I'd like all my usual features. In terminal I want it to load only the bare necessities for fast loading.

I looked at the `command-line-args` variable, but that var doesn't have flags.

Alternativley I've been considering not loading my regular init and load a custom terminal instead:
`emacs -q -l "terminal_Config.el"`
But if possible, I'd prefer to be able to tell if `-nw` was specified.

Answer (score 6):

Check the variable `window-system` or the function `display-graphic-p`.  Either will give you `nil` if you run Emacs with `-nw`.

`window-system`:

> window-system is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>   Its value is x
>   It is a terminal-local variable; global value is the same.
>
> Documentation:
>   Name of window system through which the selected frame is displayed.
>   The value is a symbol:
>    nil for a termcap frame (a character-only terminal),
>    'x' for an Emacs frame that is really an X window,
>    'w32' for an Emacs frame that is a window on MS-Windows display,
>    'ns' for an Emacs frame on a GNUstep or Macintosh Cocoa display,
>    'pc' for a direct-write MS-DOS frame.
>
> Use of this variable as a boolean is deprecated.  Instead,
>   use `display-graphic-p' or any of the other`display-*-p'
>   predicates which report frame's specific UI-related capabilities.

`display-graphic-p`:

> `(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)`
>
> Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display.
>   Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
>   frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
>   that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
>   DISPLAY can be a display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected
>   frame's display).